# 1% win rate played over 1000 times, how to calculate probabilty of results?

Tags: probability, statistics

With a coin toss, you have the probability of 99% that you will get 1 head in 10 coin tosses.

If you play a game where there is a 99% failure rate and a 1% win rate, how many times would you need to play to be sure that you will get one win?

Comment: You can't be sure, but the probability of losing $n$ times in a row will be $0.99^n$, which soon enough is overwhelmingly small.

Comment: What do you mean by "the probability of 99% that you will get 1 head in 10 coin tosses"? The probability to get exactly one head is slightly less than 1%; the probability to get one _or more_ heads is slightly greater than 99.9%. Where does your "99%" come from?

Comment: For the game with the 1% win rate, do you need _at least_ one win or _exactly_ one win. (I hope you mean "at least," or I think your question will have no answer.) And what do you mean by "to be sure"? (Is a 99% probability "sure" enough?)

Comment: Empirically, using C's `rand()` function with 100,000 runs, 0.95%  for exactly one head, 99.92% for at least one head.

Comment: The theoretical exact values are $10/1024$ and $1023/1024,$ respectively.

Comment: I need one win or more, and what I mean with "to be sure" is over 99% probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before to start playing the probability of winning in $n$ rounds is: $$p_n=1-(1-p)^n$$ where $p\le 1^-$ is probability of losing at any coin toss. The to make sure of winning you must have (!): $$1-(1-p)^n=1 \\ (1-p)^n=0 \\ n=\infty \quad(!!!)$$ Then to make sure of winning you must toss $\infty$ times . So start form right now!! Are you patient enough?!?!

Comment: Using this equation, I have a 36,6% probability of winning atleast once in 100 games? I have not studied math in over 7 years and have forgotten most of it but really need to figure this out.

Comment: Yes but you still are not quite sure! Even till $\infty$ you're sure with probability $1$ not more because of randomness. So you never can make sure in fact and this is a mathematical reality. You may win even at 1st time of toss this depends on how much lucky you are...

Comment: I understand that, I am not going to gamble or anything it's just that this math questions has been bothering me for a long time and i have forgotten how to calculate these types of things.

Answer (score 0):

You'll never be sure you win. It's always possible to fail every time. Call the amount of wins $X$, then $X \sim bin(1000, 0.01)$.